# Are one-line lambda functions bad practice per PEP8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

Recently I've found a VSCode extension that can 'beautify' code according to PEP8. I noticed a few strange changes that I would like to confirm are PEP8 and not a fault of the extension:

- All lambda functions were converted to one-line functions with return statements on the same line: `def(...): return ...`. As I understand it, `return` and `else` statements should be placed on their own line.
- All in-line comments got moved to the line above the code which makes it much more cluttered.
- 2 spaces were inserted above each function; creating a 2-line gap between the comment block and function heading.
- Certain lines of code not yet reaching the 80 char PEP8 limit were forced to a new line. For example: `(age = dict['base_age'] + years - 1)` got cut off after the dict call.

Comment: PEP8 only talks about lambdas when "binding to an identifier". i.e. `some_var = lambda ...`

Comment: This extension sounds overly opinionated and tries to justify itself by referring to PEP-8. PEP-8 says to use inline comments *sparingly* and to avoid stating the obvious; otherwise, it only mentions ensuring the `#` is preceded by at least 2 spaces and is followed by 1 space before beginning the text of the comment.

Comment: A lot of this is personal preference.  Personally, I don't like end-of-statement comments; I think vertical code is easier to read than horizontal code.  `return` statements do not need to be on a separate line.

Comment: Is this using the `Black` formatter under the hood, or something else?

Comment: @JackDeeth It was [Shift + Alt + F] which prompted me to: [pip install -U autopep8]

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is opinion-based. I'm very explicitly asking for clarifications on PEP8 and not general best practices